# AWS security group cross regions

Tags: amazon-web-services, amazon-vpc, security-groups

I am trying to set a security group `A` to allow SSH access from security group `B` in a different region. I don't have much experience with networking in general and AWS networking.

Followed the instruction from [here](https://docs.aws.amazon.com/vpc/latest/peering/vpc-peering-security-groups.html):

> You cannot reference the security group of a peer VPC that's in a different Region. Instead, use the CIDR block of the peer VPC.

So I did... I copied the CIDR from the source region and added it to the inbound rule. Still no access.

I also noted that the CIDR of the VPC of both regions was exactly the same. So I added a new one. Still no access.

I have no idea what is missing...

I know I should probably give much more details but I don't know what is safe to put in the question. Would the CIDR be safe if it is a private address? Can I post screenshots of the inbound rules?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Missed something very fundamental - when creating an inbound rule **without** a public IP, the traffic source is not the internet. So a VPC peering must be established.

Also note that this way the peer server should be accessed using its private IP address and not the public one.

Answer (score 0):

You could be looking for VPC peering. I think it will help you on the case
[VPC peering](https://i.stack.imgur.com/FyBux.png)